# Intuition behind fluctuating training loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, data-science, autoencoder

I am trying to build a convolutional autoencoder for 28x28x5 images. Below is the summary of my model:

---

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 16)        736
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 16)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 8)         1160
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 7, 7, 8)           0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 7, 7, 8)           584
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 4, 4, 8)           0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 4, 4, 8)           584
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2 (None, 8, 8, 8)           0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 8)           584
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2 (None, 16, 16, 8)         0


_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 16)        1168
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling2 (None, 28, 28, 16)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 5)         725
=================================================================
Total params: 5,541
Trainable params: 5,541
Non-trainable params: 0
```

When plotting the training and testing error per epoch, I get the following graph:
[image]
With a learning rate starting at 0.01 and reaching 0.01/750 = 0,000013333

I though the fluctuations might be because of the learning rate being too high, so I tried again with 0.00001 to 0,0000002, resulting in: 
[image]

Why is the training loss always fluctuating this much while the testing error is almost constant? Is this normal behavior? As to me it seems that they should behave similar. The initial decrease of both losses in the first graph leads me to believe the code is at least doing something right, but the rest feels wrong.

Below is my training code:

```
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(newData,
    newData, test_size=0.25)

# construct the image generator for data augmentation
aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30, width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")

model = AutoEncoder.build(width=28, height=28, depth=5)

# initialize our initial learning rate, # of epochs to train for,
# and batch size
INIT_LR = 0.001
EPOCHS = 50
BS = 16

opt = SGD(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)

model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer = opt)

H = model.fit_generator(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    validation_data=(testX, testY), steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS)
```

EDIT:

An example row in a layer of an image in the training set:

```
[ 7.41672516e-03  3.14044952e-03 -1.39656067e-02 -1.18265152e-02
  6.34765625e-03  1.27620697e-02  1.49002075e-02 -6.48117065e-03
  1.00231171e-03 -2.20489502e-03  3.14044952e-03  1.00231171e-03
  1.00231171e-03  3.14044952e-03  1.00231171e-03  4.20951843e-03
 -1.13582611e-03  1.06239319e-02  6.34765625e-03  4.20951843e-03
  1.49002075e-02  4.20951843e-03 -6.67572021e-05 -6.67572021e-05
 -1.13582611e-03 -3.27396393e-03 -5.41210175e-03 -6.48117065e-03]
```

Test set:

```
[ 1.3831139e-02  1.2762070e-02  7.4167252e-03  2.0713806e-03
 -1.1826515e-02 -7.5502396e-03  1.0023117e-03  3.1404495e-03
  2.6660919e-02 -6.6757202e-05  6.3476562e-03  2.0713806e-03
 -7.5502396e-03 -1.1358261e-03  1.0023117e-03  1.0023117e-03
 -1.1358261e-03 -6.4811707e-03  5.2785873e-03 -4.3430328e-03
  1.0023117e-03  1.1693001e-02  2.3453712e-02  1.3831139e-02
  1.9177437e-02  1.5969276e-02  2.0713806e-03  2.0713806e-03]
```

As they both come from the same input dataset I don't think this would be the problem

EDIT 2:
Training with 450000 images results in this:
[image]

Adding more training data seems to fix the problem, even though it is still weird to me why the training error fluctuates this much while the validation error does not.

EDIT 3:

Also increasing the batch size:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide number of samples in training set and test set?

Comment: possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707793/tensorflow-cnn-loss-function-goes-up-and-down-oscilating-in-tensorboard-how-t

Comment: @NikosM. , I don't believe my model is overfitting as that post suggests as the validation error remains constant.

Comment: @ChandanMS See the edit

Comment: @Lars How many images are you using to train? That's what I meant from my previous question.

Comment: @ChandanMS 3000, I have more at my disposal but I wanted to be sure it worked first. I'll try with more if that could be the issue

Comment: @Lars you can try increasing your batch size. At some point gradient is too noisy for the optimizer, increasing batch size will smooth the gradient and should improve this situation. Usually what I do is progressively increasing batch size while I decrease the learning rate. This way the gradient gets smoother when the optimizer takes finer steps.

Comment: @Lars could you give us your final word on this, for the record. Is your problem solved?

Comment: @FabienP I would say yes

Answer (score 0):

I think the model output is a constant. Can you check for that? How many samples are present in your validations set? If the model output is constant, the training loss would fluctuate( because of different samples in different batches) whereas the validation loss would remain constant. Maybe try altering the learning rate/batch size or add more data(to validation set as well).